# Does Google play store notify me if I have uploaded an apk with a different signature?

Tags: android

I recently uploaded an apk for an update of an existing application and rolled out for production.

I'm worried if I have uploaded an apk generated with a different signature (jks). 
Play store didn't notify any errors to me while I uploaded the apk.

Does it usually notify if the signature is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will see this if you try to upload an apk with the wrong signature:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Play store doesn't allow all update with different signature. To make an update to existing all ,you must sign it with same old keystore.